# How do describe grid based game using JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

### My Objective

I am designing a grid based JavaScript game loosely based on D&D. The playing field is an 8x8 grid of'dungeons'. The cells are separated by 'walls', that the adjoining cell shares.

Here is a quick sketch, showing the playing field:

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8eQS.jpg)

### My Question

How would I describe the game field in JavaScript? The obvious answer would be an array, right? But how would I then keep track of the optional walls for the cell? In my example sketch, you can see how the walls are shared. Somehow I need to be able to tell that the East Wall of the cell picture in left, is the same West Wall of the cell picture on right.

Any ideas on how I can keep track of the rooms and walls?

Thank you.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be use an array of integers and bit logic to toggle bits to indicate settings.

For example:

```
const NORTH_WALL = 1   // 0001b
const WEST_WALL = 1 << 1  // 0010b
const EAST_WALL = 1 << 2  // 0100b
const SOUTH_WALL = 1 << 3 // 1000b
const ALL_WALLS = NORTH_WALL | WEST_WALL | EAST_WALL | SOUTH_WALL
```

Then using bitwise logic you could toggle each bit.

```js
// create a 8x8 array filled with 0's
const map = new Array(8).fill().map(_ => new Array(8).fill(0))

// Toggle the bit for the wall provided, by OR'ing the wall value with the current value at the map position
const setWall = (x, y, wall) => { map[x][y] |= wall };

// Remove the bit for the wall provided by AND'ing all other walls
const removeWall = (x, y, wall) => { map[x][y] &= (ALL_WALLS - wall) };


// Check if a wall exists by AND'ing the wall with the current value and cast it to boolean (via !!)
const doesWallExist = (x, y, wall) => !!(map[x][y] & wall)

// Assuming the two cells are adjacent, it will test if there is a wall between them
const isWallBetween = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  const isVerticalWall = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) === 1)
  if (isVerticalWall) {
    const topCell = y2 > y1 ? y1 : y2
    const bottomCell = y2 > y1 ? y2 : y1
    return doesWallExist(x1, topCell, SOUTH_WALL) || doesWallExist(x2, bottomCell, NORTH_WALL)
  } else {
    const leftCell = x2 > x1 ? x1 : x2
    const rightCell = x2 > x1 ? x2 : x1
    return doesWallExist(leftCell, y1, EAST_WALL) || doesWallExist(rightCell, y2, WEST_WALL)
  }
}

// Test
console.log(map[0][0].toString(2)) // 0
setWall(0, 0, ALL_WALLS)
console.log(map[0][0].toString(2)) // 1111
removeWall(0, 0, WEST_WALL)
console.log(map[0][0].toString(2)) // 1101
console.log('does West wall exist?', doesWallExist(0, 0, WEST_WALL)) // does West wall exist? false
console.log('does North wall exist?', doesWallExist(0, 0, NORTH_WALL)) // does North wall exist? true

console.log('is there a wall between 0,0 and 0,1 ?', isWallBetween(0, 0, 0, 1)) // true
console.log('is there a wall between 0,0 and 1,0 ?', isWallBetween(0, 0, 1, 0)) // false
console.log('is there a wall between 3,6 and 4,6 ?', isWallBetween(3, 6, 4, 6)) // false
console.log('is there a wall between 5,2 and 5,3 ?', isWallBetween(5, 2, 5, 3)) // false
```

Comment: Wow! What an incredible solution. I didn't think the answer to this problem would be as complex ( relative to my experience ) as your code. I'm very impressed with the results from testing this. More importantly than you just providing a substantial portion of this simple game's logic, you left me with code to study until that "ah-ha!" moment (which most developers are, no don't, familiar with)!  I have avoided learning bitwise operations because I never saw the need in the web dev arena. Until now. Thanks so much, Rob. If your ears ringing tonight, that's my wife cursing you, lol. Study time!

Comment: You're very welcome!  I'm happy I could help :)